# Jest: Compared values have no visual difference

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I use `jest` framework to test.

I store data to create summary in object, pass it object to service that create summary and return summary with additional data. I pick desired fields from summary and compare with object that contain data to create summary and have an error, how fix it ?

```
const summaryData = {
      userHash: 'some-hash',
      hash: 'hash',
      title: 'Sumary title',
      description: 'Summary Description',
      tags: [
        'js',
        'node',
      ],
    };

    const summary = await SummaryService.createSummary(summaryData);

    expect(pick(summary, Object.keys(summaryData))).toEqual(summaryData);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe problem with mongoose model, to fix use `.toObject`

```
expect(pick(summary.toObject(), Object.keys(summaryData))).toEqual(summaryData);
```